# Create PLPGSQL Function from the Result of Another Function

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql, postgresql-9.3

Does anyone know how to set the body of a PLPGSQL function to the text of the result of another function?  For example, this is what I have tried:

```
CREATE FUNCTION "Foo"() RETURNS TEXT AS $$
    BEGIN
        RETURN 'BEGIN END;';
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

CREATE FUNCTION "Bar"() RETURNS TRIGGER AS "Foo"() LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

What I would like is for "Bar" to be created such that it is equivalent to the following:

```
CREATE FUNCTION "Bar"() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
    BEGIN END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Does anyone know how to accomplish such a thing (e.g., define a function body based on the result of another function)?  Thanks,

Comment: This can be done but it is ugly and a security nightmare. Can you explain why you want to do this? Providing the context might lead to a different way to solve your issue.

Comment: If you really want to do this, use `EXECUTE` to run the text of a `CREATE FUNCTION` clause generated with `format(...)`. But why don't you just have one function call the other?

Comment: Also note, that trigger functions can also have their own parameters, if that's what you want to achieve. f.ex. `CREATE TRIGGER ... EXECUTE PROCEDURE "Bar"('param 1 val', 42);`

Comment: I am attempting to do this because I want the same logic executed for a number of views, where the only thing changing between the functions is the view name (and associated tables).  I know I could use EXECUTE and pass the table name in, but that is less performant than if I simply created the same function 18 times without the execute statements.  I ended up going with @CraigRinger solution, which I will fully explain in an answer in case anyone else wants to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Craig Ringer for the suggestion.  This is the code that I ended up writing to generate the function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION "Foo"() RETURNS VOID AS $$
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE
            'CREATE FUNCTION ' || QUOTE_IDENT('Bar') || '() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $a$' || chr(10) ||
            'BEGIN' || chr(10) ||
            'END;' || chr(10) ||
            '$a$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;';
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```